# Visual Studio 2008 release call stack to point

Tags: c++, visual-studio, release, callstack

I've a crash on my program, that seems to happens only when I run my application in release mode.
When I start my program from Visual Studio and it crashes, I go to call stack window and I got something like this:

```
ntdll.dll!00000000774ef0c1()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!000000007749fcc4()    
ntdll.dll!00000000774934d8()    
ntdll.dll!00000000775170dd()    
ntdll.dll!00000000774db5aa()    
ntdll.dll!00000000774934d8()    
msvcr90.dll!0000000073b9cb87()  
vsgu5.dll!vuAllocRefBase::malloc(unsigned __int64 nbytes=314263224, unsigned short id=0)  Line 123 + 0x9 bytes  C++
vsgr5.dll!vrFont2D::generate(vrDrawContext * context=0x0000000012e6cab7)  Line 371 + 0x15 bytes C++
vsgr5.dll!vrFont2D::displayString(vrDrawContext * pContext=0x000000003f800000, const char * kpStr=0x000000003f800000)  Line 698 + 0xf bytes C++
vsgr5.dll!vrFont2D::displayStringAt(vrDrawContext * context=0x0000000012f2cac8, const char * str=0x0000000002c6cdc8, const vuVec4<float> & color={...}, float x=-16.634912, float y=-188.33476, float z=0.00000000)  Line 786   C++
vsgr5.dll!vrString::draw(vrDrawContext * pContext=0x0000000012bb46b8, const vuVector<vrDrawFunc::InstanceRecord,vuLockOpen,vuAllocSTL<vrDrawFunc::InstanceRecord>,vuAllocRaw> * pInstances=0x0000000012bb2cb8)  Line 290 + 0x54 bytes   C++
vpoverlay5.dll!vpOverlay2DText::draw(const vsChannel * kpVsChannel=0x0000000012bb2cb8, vrDrawContext * pContext=0x0000000000000002)  Line 289   C++
vpoverlay5.dll!vpOverlayDrawMgr::drawOverlay(const vsChannel * channel=0x000000001462c040, vrDrawContext * context=0x0000000013293cd0)  Line 258 + 0x12 bytes   C++
vsgs5.dll!vsChannel::draw(vrDrawContext * context=0x0000000012bb6018)  Line 3134    C++
vsgs5.dll!vsPipeline::processDraw(vsChannel * channel=0x0000000012bb2cb8, vrDrawContext * context=0x0000000012bb46b8)  Line 2857    C++
vsgs5.dll!vsPipeline::draw()  Line 3528 + 0x2d bytes    C++
vsgs5.dll!vsPipeline::endFrame()  Line 2159 C++
vsgs5.dll!vsServiceMgr::endFrame()  Line 862    C++
VegaPrime.dll!000007feda746b67()    
VegaPrime.dll!000007feda7443a8()    
VegaPrime.dll!000007feda73545a()    
VegaPrime.dll!000007feda75da6e()    
QtCore4.dll!000000006663a38b()  
msvcr90.dll!0000000073b52fdf()
```

Is there a way to find, for example from this line

```
        VegaPrime.dll!000007feda746b67()
```

The corresponding line of code, or method that it's called?

Comment: If you have debug symbols (more or less because of some optimizations) yes it's possible (as you see stack from vsgs5.dll)

Comment: I have not debug symbols because I'm release mode. Can I create them mantaining release optimizations?

Comment: Yes, you can have PDB in release mode (with optimizations too) but of course trace will be coarser (for example because of inlining or other optimizations).

Comment: Ok thanks I'll check project options.